# Can't Sync iPod Touch (5th Generation) Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ipod

When I try to sync my iTouch 5G with Rythmbox or Banshee, I get an error saying: "Unhandled Lockdown error (-256)" This is a new iPod and I really want to sync it with my Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have iOS8.x? If so
`libimobiledevice` may not support iOS 8 yet. The only solution is to wait until that's updated.